# A button disappears after click event on mobile

Tags: mobile, redirect

Whenever the page redirects (either due to refresh or a link out click), the button always disappears before all other elements. It's not visible on laptop, but quite visible on mobile devices. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I found that it was due to the `backface-visibility: hidden;` I set upon the button to prevent the `transition`ing div from flickering. It looks like when pages redirect, those div are turned "backfaced" before being replaced by another page.